# How to set up MIT Scheme for 6.001 in Ubuntu 8.10

Tags: linux, ubuntu, scheme, lisp, mit-scheme

I play to self-study 6.001 with the video lectures and lecture handouts. However, I have some problems setting up MIT Scheme in Ubuntu (intrepid).

I used package management and installed MIT-Scheme, but it's obviously the wrong version to use. It should be 7.5.1 instead of 7.7.90

I followed the instructions from this website (http://ocw.mit.edu/OcwWeb/Electrical-Engineering-and-Computer-Science/6-001Spring-2005/Tools/detail/linuxinstall.htm)

So far, I've downloaded the tar file, and extracted to /usr/local. I have no idea what step 3 means.

Then I entered command

> scheme -large -band 6001.com -edit

and the error is

> Not enough memory for this configuration.
> I tried to run under sudo mode, and this time the error is different
> Unable to allocate process table.
>
> Inconsistency detected

I have close to 1GB of free memory, with ample HDD space. What should I do to successfully set this up?

Comment: I've installed mit-scheme through package manager, but the version is 7.7.90, while the version used in 6.001 is 7.5.1.

There are also 6.001 specific settings in the one on the MIT website (which I can't get it working).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step 3 means that you should type `export MITSCHEME_6001_DIRECTORY=${your_problems_path}`. If you don't want to type it every time you launch Scheme, you should put it as a string in your ~/.bash_profile file(in case you use bash)

About the problem itself, Google instantly suggests a solution:
`sudo sysctl -w vm.mmap_min_addr=0`(taken from http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=4868292)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the package manager, you may also want to compile the portable C sources for Unix. I am using it happily.